# Defining constraints in Jenetics

Tags: java, optimization, genetic-algorithm, jenetics

I have previously worked with the [MOEA Framework](http://moeaframework.org/), which knows the concept of constraints. That is, a solution to a problem might have a good fitness, but is infeasible. For instance, when working with the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), a particular combination of items may lead to a high profit, but their weight exceeds the knapsack's capacity. A corresponding fitness function would include lines like:

```
// Set the fitness (=> profit) of the solution (=> knapsack).
solution.setObjective(0, profit)
// Set the constrain (=> 0.0 if OK, , otherwise the distance to the boundary).
solution.setConstraint(0, (weight <= capacity) ? 0.0 : weight - capacity)
```

Another example in case of a multi-objective knapsack problem would be the constraint that a knapsack is not allowed to use items which are already used in another knapsack.

Has [Jenetics](http://jenetics.io/) something similar? Or how could I encode constraints as part of the fitness function (or somewhere else)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Jenetic [v5.0.0](https://github.com/jenetics/jenetics/releases/tag/v5.0.0), both [`phenotypeValidator`](http://jenetics.io/javadoc/jenetics/4.4/io/jenetics/engine/Engine.Builder.html#phenotypeValidator-java.util.function.Predicate-) and [`genotypeValidator`](http://jenetics.io/javadoc/jenetics/4.4/io/jenetics/engine/Engine.Builder.html#genotypeValidator-java.util.function.Predicate-) have been removed, but it is now possible to define a [`Constraint`](http://jenetics.io/javadoc/jenetics/5.0/io/jenetics/engine/Constraint.html) (see also [user guide](http://jenetics.io/manual/manual-5.0.0.pdf), section 2.5):

```
Engine.builder(/* ... */)
        .constraint(Constraint.of(phenotype -> /* test validity */)
        .build();
```

One can also implement `Constraint`'s [`repair`](http://jenetics.io/javadoc/jenetics/5.0/io/jenetics/engine/Constraint.html#repair-io.jenetics.Phenotype-long-) method to try to repair given individuals.

Please note (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57016541/3429133)):

> It [the `Constraint` interface] is meant as the last line of defense, when it comes to check the validity of an individual. […] The second important method [besides `test`] of the `Constraint` is the `repair` method. This method tries to *fix* the given individual. Without defining this method, only a new, random phenotype is created.

Answer (score 3):

[Jenetics](http://jenetics.io/) doesn't support *constraints* directly. You can set a [`phenotypeValidator`](http://jenetics.io/javadoc/jenetics/io/jenetics/engine/Engine.Builder.html#phenotypeValidator-java.util.function.Predicate-) in the [`Engine.Builder`](http://jenetics.io/javadoc/jenetics/io/jenetics/engine/Engine.Builder.html). This will reject `Phenotypes` and recreate *invalid* individuals. Not exactly a constraint, but a kind of. The second possibility is to return the minimum fitness value for all objectives for such values.

Answer (score 0):

Please also consider validating your constraints within the fitness function itself and return a value is the opposite of what you are optimising for. This might slow down the overall performance but allows you to validate the result on a higher level.

E.g. if your maximising for a double value just return the lowest negative double as a result of the fitness function, if the optimised solution does not pass the constraints.

Comment: Thank you, but this is basically the same as what [Franz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53415479/3429133) already said: "The second possibility is to return the minimum fitness value for all objectives for such values."